# Using Apache Spark to find frequent contiguous

Tags: apache-spark

How can I use Apache Spark to find contiguous sequences

Comment: What is the maximum length of `S`? What are the maximum values for `L` and Minimum Support?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try taking inital string, splitting it into unique subsequences of different length, then broadcasting intial sequence over them and filtering matched. Something like this would work in a `spark-shell`

```
val s = "AATTGTGTGTGTGATTTTTTAATG" //your string

val s_broadcast = sc.broadcast(s) //broadcast version

val A = 2 // min length of substring
val B = 3 // max length of substring
val C = 3 // min support
val L = s.size //length of the string

sc.parallelize(
    for{
        i <- A to B
        j <- 0 to (L - i)
    } yield (j,i+j)
) // generating paris of substrings
.map{case(j,i)=>s_broadcast.value.substring(j,i)}
.distinct // if optimization is needed, this step is a place to start
.filter(x=>s_broadcast.value.indexOf(x*C)>=0)
.collect
.map(_*C)
```

EDITED:
as an after though - here's code which will return LONGEST substrings. The previous code has `C` fixed, this one tries longest.

```
val s = "AATTGTGTGTGTGTGATTTTTTAATG" //your string

val s_broadcast = sc.broadcast(s) //broadcast version

val A = 2 // min length of substring
val B = 3 // max length of substring
val C = 3 // min support
val L = s.size //length of the string

sc.parallelize(
    for{
        i <- A to B
        j <- 0 to (L - i)
    } yield (j,i+j)
) // generating paris of substrings
.map{case(j,i)=>s_broadcast.value.substring(j,i)}
.distinct // if optimization is needed, this step is a place to start
.flatMap(x=>
    for{
        v <- C to L/A
    } yield x->v
) //making "AB"->3 pairs, which will result in search for "ABABAB"
.filter{case(x,v)=>s_broadcast.value.indexOf(x*v)>=0}
.groupByKey //grouping same substrings of different length
.map{case(k,v)=>k->v.max} //getting longer substring
.collect //bringing substring to the driver
.map{case(k,v)=>k*v}
```

Comment: thanks the output of this code is Array(TT, GT, TG) and is not contiguous subsequence of the input string s = AATTGTGTGTGTGATTTTTTAATG.

Comment: adding `.map(_*C)` as last line

Comment: Much thanks, works perfectly, but on trying to get my input from the local machine with val s= sc.textFile("file:///tmp/input.txt") and the broadcast variable with val s_broadcast = sc.broadcast("file:///tmp/input.txt"), is given error:  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:at the point:.map{case(j,i)=>s_broadcast.value.substring(j,i)} in the code. I will appreciate your help in fixing the error.

Comment: I have been able to clear the error using this code: val seq = sc.textFile("file:///tmp/input.txt")                                                                    val fseq = seq.flatMap(_.toString).collect.mkString("") and                         val s_broadcast = sc.broadcast(fseq) //broadcast version. Please let me know if there are better ways to do this. Thanks

Comment: how can I introduce hamming distance into the algorithm, so that the frequent contiguous subsequence will not be exact search of the string. For example, given AATGTTGTAGGGTTTCCTA, if the hamming distance is one(1) and length is three(3) and minimum support is two(2) the GTTGTA will be the contiguous frequent sequence. I have been on this for a while, I will appreciate your input. Thanks.

Comment: You might choose to form this as a separate question though. I could be a bit ugly with Strings though (even more ugly than it is now). If this is for some theoretical results - you probably should consider something other than Strings to build your framework on!